# OnItemClickListener e OnItemLongClickListener funcionando juntos

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma listView dentro de um Fragment e a partir de cada item abro uma activity diferente, mas depois que botei um OnItemLongClickListener para abrir um AlertDialog quando cada item for pressionado o OnListItemClick "parou" de funcionar. Como é um Array Adapter personalizado tenho um RelativeLayout com 16dp de padding, e o OnListItemClick só funciona clicando fora do Relative Layout

Esse é o XML com os itens personalizados

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/lista_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_item_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="43sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="@string/txt_lista" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_list"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Essa a parte com o OnItemClickListener e o OnItemLongClickListener

```
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, container, false);
    ArrayList<Itens> itens = new ArrayList<Itens>();
    itens.add(new Itens("Primeira", R.drawable.img));
    itens.add(new Itens("Segunda", R.drawable.img));
    itens.add(new Itens("Terceira", R.drawable.img));

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), itens, R.color.lista_background);

    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id){
            if(position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PrimeiraActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if(position == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SegundaActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            if(position == 2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TerceiraActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position == 0) {
                PrimeiroDialogFragment dialogFragment = new PrimeiroDialogFragment();
                dialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "sobre");
            }
            if(position == 1) {
                SegundoDialogFragment dialogFragment = new SegundoDialogFragment();
                dialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "sobre");


            }
            if(position == 2) {
                TerceiroDialogFragment dialogFragment = new TerceiroDialogFragment();
                dialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "sobre");
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    return rootView;
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer! xD

Comment: Eu quero que quando eu clique o item tenha um comportamento (abra uma activity) e quando eu segure ele tenha outro (exiba o DialogFragment). Tá funcionando, mas o problema é que eu tenho um RelativeLayout (ele tem um background amarelo) pra personalizar os itens, o problema é que só funciona qnd eu Clico fora desse retângulo amarelo, pois tem um padding de 16dp. Não sei se tem como enviar foto aqui, seria melhor pra explicar

Comment: Resolvi. Foi só tirar o android:clickable e o android:longClickable